# In what way to reset a concatenated Ticket number using counter and a time function in VB.Net and MS Access as its database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, counter

I am struggling of generating a ticket number in my program. I am creating a system that a user can generate their own ticket number so that it can quickly recognize their requests or their problems. Is it possible that a Ticket Number can be reset on a desired time? Let's say my conditional statement in "Hour" function is greater or lesser than 23 (until midnight or dawn), would the MS Access Database resets it's counter to 1 again when it exceeds on desired time?

Here's my code:

```
'This is the main menu
Public Class MISMenu

 Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click 'Button to go to the Trouble Ticket.vb

Trouble_Ticket.Show()

    Dim hours As Int32 = DateTime.Now.Hour 'My time function
    Dim numberOfEmployees As Int32 = 0
    'Database connection stuff
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    con = New OleDbConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MIS\MIS\LoginMIS1.mdb"
    con.Open()
    'I'm using Count function to count the counter variable from MS Access database
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select count(ID) From TroubleTicks", con)
    numberOfEmployees = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()

End Sub 
End Class

'Trouble Ticket.vb
Public Class Trouble_Ticket

Public dateAndTime As Date 'my date function
Public counter As Integer 'variable for incrementing a number

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim con As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim numberOfEmployees As Int32 = 0

    Dim hours As Int32 = DateTime.Now.Hour 'my time function
    dateAndTime = Now 'to currently display the date

    'conditional statements
    If hours < 12 Then
        'incrementing a counter
        counter += 1
        'if this variable below is not equal to 0 then it will continue to increment the counter that is existing to the MS Access database but it isn't working
        If numberOfEmployees <> 0 Then
            counter += 1
            'Database connection stuff
            con = New OleDbConnection()
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MIS\MIS\LoginMIS1.mdb"
            con.Open()
            'Count function again to count the Counter Variable from MS Access database
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select count(ID) From TroubleTicks", con)
            numberOfEmployees = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            counter = numberOfEmployees
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End If
    End If

   'I concatenated the date,time and the counter variable that will display as a label
Label5.Text = Format(dateAndTime, "yyyyMMdd" & "-").ToString & counter

End Sub
End class
```

Here's the images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TScJI.jpg)
The Main Menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvvNJ.jpg)
Trouble Ticket.vb form where the users enter their concerns or problems and this is where the Ticket Number is generated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jAY4.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwKfK.jpg)
The program goes well when you submit it many times but when you re-open the form from the MISMenu, the counter resets to 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBRmk.jpg)
Here's my MS Access database

Would somebody help me please to solve this problem?

I'm very sorry for my terrible English, and I'm hoping that my question will be answered soon!